# Where can I download Bootstraps popover.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and still learning. Does anyone know where to download popover.js from, and how to install it?

I've tried to find it in the bootstrap site and I have had no luck finding it.

Can anyone help me? I'm using bootstrap 3.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Just download Bootstrap.  It's all included. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download  Or include it from a CDN, it contains all the plugins.  Just make sure to also include jQuery.

Comment: @close voters: that close reason is completely invalid for this question. Asking for support on libraries etc are totally on topic.

Comment: First of all, if you want to be a software developer you should learn how to use search. It's a must have skill. Use it to find how to include js files in your project.
[**Download popover.js**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/popover.js)

Comment: Go to the Bootstrap [Customize page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). Select the components you need. Click "Compile & Download". *Tip:* If you only need one or two components, click "Toggle all" to uncheck all the checkboxes, then check the checkboxes for the components you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap.js you should already have the necessary code to use a Popover. In bootstrap.js v3.1.1 The comment block for Popover starts on line 1424, and the rest of the Popover class follows.
bootstrap.js lines 1424 - 1431:

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: popover.js v3.1.1
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */
```